# Server CPU stays on 100% when e-commerce site runs

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis-7, cpu-usage

I have developed an e-commerce website on .NET umbraco. After deploying it i have made a load test with 100 users ([loadimapct](http://loadimpact.com/)).When ever more than 30 users tried to access the site,it freezes and CPU usage stays at 100% till the test is over. The site is accessing an indexing engine (Fact-Finder) internally which is deployed on a Tomcat Server.
Here is a snap shot of the condition.

[Snapshot](http://my.jetscreenshot.com/7391/20121106-xhtd-222kb.jpg)

I have checked the site with profilers but there is no heavy process running that i can see.

I have made a check with DebugDiag tool ([Troubleshooting High CPU in an IIS 7.x Application Pool](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool) ).It indicates high CPU usage but I can't understand which page or resource from my website makes this,So i have attached a copy of report.
[Detail Report Link](http://www.streamfile.com/myid/nIDcoYgd3tW9)

can any one Help on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms you see can be result of various factors.

Trouble shooting and debug these kind of problems the below tools will assist you.

1. [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26798)
2. Performance Monitor (`perfmon.exe` which comes along with windows)

You can set up debug diag to capture a memory dump when the CPU usage exceeds and use the Automated dump analysis which may help you in identifying the root cause.

For a more detailed step by step explanation you can follow steps in [Troubleshooting High CPU in an IIS 7.x Application Pool](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have made a test with Debug Diag and the result says High CPU usage.But i am unable to identify which process takes the cpu high.I have attached a detailed report in my edited question.